# How to install numpy for blender-python (OSX)

Tags: python, installation

I've been googling for this, and I can't find a definitive answer.

Here are of the options I can find:

1. https://plus.google.com/106742462387083223310/posts/696yEuzhf2b
   which suggests: '**sudo python3.2 setup.py install --install-lib /usr/lib/blender/scripts/modules/**'

   but I don't see how that has anything to do with numpy, so I'm going to skip this one for now.
2. http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?324822-Another-NumPy-issue
   Install numpy using existing Python3, and then manually copy /numpy folder over
   I've tried this, as below, and it fails just the same as in that thread
3. Delete Blender's Python, forcing it to fall back upon  the system Python installation
   I'm reluctant to do this as I want this module to be publicly usable, and I don't like the idea of requiring people to cobble their blender to make it work.

---

So, going with (2):

I'm on OS X and I have a separate Python3 courtesy of Homebrew.

```
piBookAir:~ pi$ pip install numpy

piBookAir:~ pi$ python3
Python 3.3.4 (default, Mar  8 2014, 14:52:56) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> print( numpy.__file__ )
/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py
```

So now I copy the /numpy folder over to ~/BlenderScripts/modules/
(I have set ~/BlenderScripts as my scripts folder)

I restart Blender, go into the Python console:
[image]

The error is "**ImportError: cannot import name add_newdocs**"

What am I doing wrong?

Also, if I may bundle two questions into one, can I copy my ~/BlenderScripts onto a fresh system (maybe with a different operating system) and expect a script that imports numpy to still work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numpy is included in Blender 2.70 on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

Comment: Super! I was on 2.69

Comment: I would very much like the answer for the more general question: How do I force Blender to use the system-installed python runtime over the bundled?

Comment: It won't use other python distribution, but using the following code you can install other packages using pip:
https://github.com/pelednoam/mmvt/blob/master/src/misc/install_blender_reqs.py